# JSQMessagesViewController add image to bubble

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'd like to add image to message bubbles using JSQMessagesViewController.

I tried add UIImageView to

```
JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell.messageBubbleContainerView
```

But the message text will be covered by image.

I would like to show the image view on either right or left side of the bubble, and leave the message text as they were.

How could I do that?

Comment: Could you provide the code to what you have tried. There may be a way to add constraints to help. Also if you have any images of what you are going for or what you have with a description of what you would like changed about it. That may assist others in pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: @DanielLeonard, I finally able to add the image by provide a custom xib file which is subclass of JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell. Thanks anyway